# Passing # character in url with python

Tags: python, url

I have the following code:

```
@app.route('/famcall/Audio/AudioMng_PlayDTMF/<string:output_stream>/<string:dtmf>/<string:duration>/<string:gap>', methods=['GET'])
    def fam_audio_play_dtmf(output_stream, dtmf, duration, gap):
        params = [self.mapAudioOutputStream.business_to_tech(output_stream), dtmf, duration, gap]
        return self.call_fam_function_and_wait_response("AudioMng_PlayDTMF", params)
```

and I want to use the character # in my url because it´s a value that can be used for dtmf. Is there an encode function in python which can help me in this? Or should I forget this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a replacement: replace `#` with `%23`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [urllib.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) (Python 2) or [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) (Python 3) to escape your dtmf value or anything else that might contain reserved characters.

Comment: How can I use this with my code? I´ve used it like this and it doesn´t work: 
    params = 
    [self.mapAudioOutputStream.business_to_tech(output_stream), dtmf, 
    duration, gap]
            data = quote(params)

Comment: @H.Avram - it takes one string, not a list. `urllib.quote(dtmf)`. The point is that it covers all reserved characters, not just `#`. EG `urllib.quote('foo#bar:baz')` returns `'foo%23bar%3Abaz'`.